# Mongoose Subdocument will not update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am having trouble figuring out if I designed the schema correctly because I am receiving a 500 error when attempting to PATCH changes of the roles property from a profile. (Note: The 500 error just responds with an empty {}, so it isn't really informative)

Below is the profile schema:

```
var ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  roles: [{
    application: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'Application'
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      enum: [ 'admin', 'author', 'publisher' ]
    }
  }]
});
```

Each profile has a role for an application, and when I send the request to the controller action 'update', it fails:

profile update controller:

```
// Updates an existing Profile in the DB
export function update(req, res) {
  try {
    if (req.body._id) {
      delete req.body._id;
    }

   console.log('ENDPOINT HIT...');
   console.log(`REQUEST PARAM ID: ${req.params.id}`);
   console.log('REQUEST BODY:');
   console.log(req.body);
   console.log('ENTIRE REQUEST: ');

   return Profile.findByIdAsync(req.params.id)
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(saveUpdates(req.body))
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));

 } catch(ex) {
     console.error('FAILED TO UPDATE PROFILE');
     return handleError(res);
   }
}
```

I made sure that the id and body was being sent properly, and I am hitting the end point.

This is an example of the request body JSON:

```
{ 
  _id: 57e58ad2781fd340563e29ff,
  __updated: Thu Oct 27 2016 15:41:12 GMT-0400 (EDT),
  __created: Fri Sep 23 2016 16:04:34 GMT-0400 (EDT),
  name: 'test',
  __v: 11,
  roles:[ 

   { application: 57b70937c4b9fe460a235375,
     role: 'admin',
     _id: 58125858a36bd76d8111ba16 },

   { application: 581b299f0145b48adf8f57bd,
     role: 'publisher',
     _id: 581b481898eefb19ed8a73ee } 
   ]

 }
```

When I try to find the Profile by Id, the promise chain goes straight to the catch(handleError(res)); part of the code and shows an empty object in my console.

My handle error function:

```
 function handleError(res, statusCode) {
   console.error('HANDLE PROFILE ERROR: ', statusCode);
   statusCode = statusCode || 500;
   return function(err) {
     console.error('PROFILE ERROR:');
     console.error(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
     res.status(statusCode).send(err);
   };
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I am realizing the code is breaking when it hits my saveUpdates function (*Note*: I am using lodash):

```
function saveUpdates(updates) {
  /// the code is fine here ///
  return function(entity) {
    /// once it enters in here, is where it begins to break ///
    var updated = _.merge(entity, updates);

    if(updated.roles.length != updates.roles.length) {
      updated.roles = updates.roles;
    }

    for(var i in updates.roles) {
      updated.roles.set(i, updates.roles[i]);
    }
    return updated.saveAsync()
     .then(updated => {
        return updated;
      });
    };
}
```

Comment: to see the error `findByIdAsync(...).catch((err) => { console.log(err); handleError(res); })`

Comment: Can you tell us, what is on `req.params.id` exactly please? what is showed to you by `console.log(\`REQUEST PARAM ID: ${req.params.id}\`);`

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT, when I console.log the params.id -- this is what I retrieve:

   ` REQUEST PARAM ID: 57bd9db4f33dcd03c3fd9990`

Comment: ok try `findOne({ _id: req.params.id })` _(I cannot find findByIdAsync() mongoose documentation)_

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT, so I realized that if I remove the saveUpdates function call from my promise chain -- and switch the model's method to `Profile.findOneAndUpdate` -- then the error disappears. I am convinced that my saveUpdates function is broken now.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson learned: Read Documentation properly.

Since I am using bluebird promises for this application, I forgot to use `.spread()` within my `saveUpdates()` callback function.

Solution:

```
function saveUpdates(updates) {
  return function(entity) {
    var updated = _.merge(entity, updates);
    if(updated.roles.length != updates.roles.length) {
       updated.roles = updates.roles;
    }

    for(var i in updates.roles) {
      updated.roles.set(i, updates.roles[i]);
    }

    return updated.saveAsync()
      // use `.spread()` and not `.then()` //
      .spread(updated => {
        return updated;
      });
   };
 }
```

I want to thank the following SOA that led to this conclusion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25799076/5994486

Also, here is the link to the bluebird documentation in case anyone was curious on `.spread()`: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html